# Updating the input value on button click Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

For The code below, when the button is clicked, it's supposed to update the name of the text. ie hisally, hellosally, supsally,
but instead the current is hitomsally, hellotomsally, suptomsally.
i m wondering is there any way to update the name while keeping the text hi,hellop and sup.
Many thanks

```js
$(".ok").on('click', function() {
  var set = $(this).closest('tr').find('.done').val();
  if (set) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.text').each(function() {
      $(this).val($(this).attr("data-value") + set);
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td>
     <input type="button" value="ok" class="ok"></td>
    <td>done<input type="text" value="sally" class="done" \> </td>
    <td>text1<textarea class="text" data-value="hitom">hitom</textarea> </td>
    <td>text2<textarea class="text" data-value="hellotom">hellotom</textarea> </td>
    <td>text3<textarea class="text" data-value="suptom">suptom</textarea> </td>

  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: It seems to be working. You might need to clarify your question.

Comment: You are using name and text for everything. Please use the proper names of the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change your `data-value` to only the values that you want to prepend in `textarea`

```js
$(".ok").on('click', function() {
  var set = $(this).closest('tr').find('.done').val();
  if (set) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.text').each(function() {
      $(this).val($(this).attr("data-value") + set);
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td>
     <input type="button" value="ok" class="ok"></td>
    <td>done<input type="text" value="sally" class="done" \> </td>
    <td>text1<textarea class="text" data-value="hi">hitom</textarea> </td>
    <td>text2<textarea class="text" data-value="hello">hellotom</textarea> </td>
    <td>text3<textarea class="text" data-value="sup">suptom</textarea> </td>

  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `data-value` contains wrong values for the textareas, and you are actually concatenating the value of the textbox to them. Correct the values in the `data-value` attributes, and you will be done!

```js
$(".ok").on('click', function() {
  var set = $(this).closest('tr').find('.done').val();
  if (set) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.text').each(function() {
      $(this).val($(this).attr("data-value") + set);
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td>
     <input type="button" value="ok" class="ok"></td>
    <td>done<input type="text" value="sally" class="done" \> </td>
    <td>text1<textarea class="text" data-value="hi">hitom</textarea> </td>
    <td>text2<textarea class="text" data-value="hello">hellotom</textarea> </td>
    <td>text3<textarea class="text" data-value="sup">suptom</textarea> </td>

  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am deleting the 'tom' from every string.

```js
$(".ok").on('click', function() {
  var set = $(this).closest('tr').find('.done').val();
  if (set) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.text').each(function() {
      $(this).val($(this).attr("data-value").replace(/tom/g,"")+set);
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td>
     <input type="button" value="ok" class="ok"></td>
    <td>done<input type="text" value="sally" class="done" \> </td>
    <td>text1<textarea class="text" data-value="hitom">hitom</textarea> </td>
    <td>text2<textarea class="text" data-value="hellotom">hellotom</textarea> </td>
    <td>text3<textarea class="text" data-value="suptom">suptom</textarea> </td>

  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```