# Change textbox value when click link in jquery div based dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created HTML where I want if user hit `<img src="https://www.fast2sms.com/panel/img/icons/add1.png" class="add-img">` then `123456789` will fill in textbox dynamically `(each-one for different value as in <a> tags)` and the border of that selected div will red. I try to search this method on google but I couldn't find that and I am familiar with Js and Jquery so I cant do this But Stack-overflow is developer friends and here millions of well developers and students who helps everyone. Please help to how i made this function.

My code is given below:

```
<div id="scroll" style="overflow: auto;height:375px">                                
<div class="row pt-5 pb-5 mb-5 this_contact">                                        
<div class="col-xs-3"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/2x/administrator-male.png" height="40"></div>
<div class="col-xs-9 no-col-r">
<span class="f_17">Shiv</span>
<a data-number="123456789" class="toggle_contact"><img src="https://www.fast2sms.com/panel/img/icons/add1.png" class="add-img"></a><br>
<span class="f_13">123456789</span><br>
</div>
</div>                         


<div class="row pt-5 pb-5 mb-5 this_contact">                                        
<div class="col-xs-3"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/2x/administrator-male.png" height="40"></div>
<div class="col-xs-9 no-col-r">
<span class="f_17">Dummy</span>
<a data-number="1253648595" class="toggle_contact"><img src="https://www.fast2sms.com/panel/img/icons/add1.png" class="add-img"></a><br>
<span class="f_13">1253648595</span><br>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no text box in your HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating the input value on button click Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916929/updating-the-input-value-on-button-click-jquery)

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda I seen your link thanks for that, but my question is so diffrent of that, I am talking about div click event you show one btn for all. Links have table method I have textbox div method. Please remove the `That solve my problem` tags from my question sir, and help to make this code in JSFiddle.

Comment: @Mamun Yes , I not mention there , we considered it anythings with thats IDs and Class, Whatever, This is not big mistake and issue, Pls help to provide its JSFIDDLE

Comment: Hi @J.Doe, you'r question was not clear, Please provide some required data, so we solve it

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda Please have a short look this img link `<img src="https://i.ibb.co/Lt43FLC/Capture.png" alt="Capture" border="0">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly,

```js
$(function(){
$('.toggle_contact').click(function(){

 var contactNumber = $(this).data('number');
 $(this).parents('.this_contact').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
 $(this).parents().find('input:text').val(contactNumber);
})
})
```

```css
.selected{
  background-color:red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroll" style="overflow: auto;height:375px">                                
<div class="row pt-5 pb-5 mb-5 this_contact">
<div class="col-xs-3"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/2x/administrator-male.png" height="40"></div>
<div class="col-xs-9 no-col-r">
<span class="f_17">Shiv</span>
<a data-number="123456789" class="toggle_contact"><img src="https://www.fast2sms.com/panel/img/icons/add1.png" class="add-img"></a><br>
</div>
</div>                         


<div class="row pt-5 pb-5 mb-5 this_contact">                                        
<div class="col-xs-3"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/2x/administrator-male.png" height="40"></div>
<div class="col-xs-9 no-col-r">
<span class="f_17">Dummy</span>
<a data-number="1253648595" class="toggle_contact"><img src="https://www.fast2sms.com/panel/img/icons/add1.png" class="add-img"></a><br>
</div>
</div>

<input type="text" name='name' value="">
```

Comment: Thank you , you understood correct, but I want one textbox for this code if user click multi btn then the older number replace to new number and that selected div boder color will change to we can identify the selected div as btn

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: What about the selected div color change to I can see which div contact I was selected `https://jsfiddle.net/techWorld/p6m3eb5L/1/`

Comment: I am really awaiting for your last update sir, its ugate, Please help me

Comment: Updated the answer @J.Doe

Comment: Are, you IITian? genius , anything you can do, where from you study in india tell me I also want learn from there. and this is true , I am in class 12th currently in India

Comment: is it possible to chnage icon of plus of selected div. means if user click div then the plus icon also change to any check image else default

Comment: I am awating for your responds